# Help me to prove this statement about quadratic equations? (from Gelfand's Algebra).

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

$ x^2+px+q=0 ${p,q are integers; a,b are roots}. Prove $a^n+b^n$(n is any natural number) is an integer.

This is the third part of the problem.I have previously proved that $a^2+b^2$ and $a^3+b^3$ are integers using the binomial theorem and vieta's laws$(a+b=-p, ab=q)$. Using the same approach here,i have:

$a^n+b^n = (a+b)^n-a^{n-1}b-a^{n-2}b^2...-ab^{n-1}$

$=(-p)^n-ab(a^{n-2}+a^{n-3}b+...+b^{n-2})$

$=(-p)^n-q((a+b)^{n-2}...))$

Here i am stumped.I think that depending on whether n is even or odd the equation reduces to the previous two cases i have already proven.How do i state this formally?

PS: i am an independent learner without much experience with proofs.Please give a concise proof if you can(or a really detailed hint).

Comment: Alternately, use the fact that both *a* and *b* are of the form $t\pm\sqrt u$, with *t* and *u* rational, and then expand $a^n$ and $b^n$ using [Newton's binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). All odd powers of the radical will cancel each other out. Now all that's left to do is showing that the remaining rational expression is an integer, which, given the relation between *t* and *u*, will most probably not be too hard to prove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is done by induction:
$$ P(n) \ \ \ \  \ \ \ a^n+b^n \text{ is an integer }$$

- **Basis steps**  first we know that $a+b,a^2+b^2 $ are all integers as you proved, so $P(1),P(2)$ are true. (you can also notice that $a+b=-p$ and $a^2+b^2=p^2-2q$)
- **Induction step** assume that $P(k)$ is true for all integers $k$ such that $k\leq n$ and let's prove $P(n+1)$. Using the fact the $a,b$ are roots of $x^2+px+q=0$ then $a^2+pa+q=0$ and $b^2+pb+q=0$  a multiplication of this two equations by $a^{n-1},b^{n-1}$ respectively gives us: $$a^{n+1}+pa^n+qa^{n-1}=0\\ b^{n+1}+pb^n+qb^{n-1}=0 $$
  hence $a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}=-p(a^n+b^n)-q(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1})$ is an integer using because $a^{n}+b^{n}$ is an integer (From IH $P(n)$ is true) and $a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}$ is an integer  (From IH $P(n-1)$ is true). As a conclution $P(n+1)$ is true and the induction terminates.

Comment: In fact this is a strong version of induction,  As a basis step we prove $P(1)$ is true and then we assume that $P(1),\cdots,P(n)$ are true and prove that $P(n+1)$ is true. And as a conclusion $P(n)$ is true for all integers

Comment: I finally understood your proof.Thank you.  :D

Answer (score 0):

It can be proved by induction on $n$, as follows:

From

$x^2 + px + q = 0 \tag{1}$

it follows that the roots $a$, $b$ satisfy

$a + b = -p, \tag{2}$

$ab = q; \tag{3}$

from (2), (3) we have

$p^2 = (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 = a^2 + 2q + b^2, \tag{4}$

or

$a^2 + b^2 = p^2 - 2q \in \Bbb Z, \tag{5}$

since $p, q \in \Bbb Z$.  Also, since

$(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3 = a^3 + b^3 + 3ab(a + b), \tag{6}$

it follows that

$a^3 + b^3 = (a + b)^3 - 3ab(a + b) = -p^3 + 3pq \in \Bbb Z. \tag{7}$

Now assume that $m \ge 3$ and that $a^k + b^k \in \Bbb Z$ for $1 \le k \le m$; note we have established the case $m = 3$ in the above.  Then

$a^{m+ 1} + b^{m + 1} = (a + b)(a^m + b^m) - (a^mb + ab^m) = (a + b)(a^m + b^m) - ab(a^{m - 1} + b^{m - 1})$
$= -p(a^m + b^m) - q(a^{m - 1} + b^{m - 1}); \tag{8}$

by hypothesis, $a^m + b^m, a^{m - 1} + b^{m - 1} \in \Bbb Z$; since $p, q \in \Bbb Z$, it follows that $a^{m + 1} + b^{m + 1} \in \Bbb Z$ as well.  This completes the induction and shows that $a^n + b^n \in \Bbb Z$ for all $n \ge 1$.  ***QED.***